# Ionic file structure wrong

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i am new to ionic and there are some problems i am facing like the file structure is very different. like there is no `lib` folder no `app.js` file there is no `angular.module('myApp')` code anywhere.
help me out with it my whole work is pending.
i have tried re-installing ionic and cordove but didn't made any difference.
image attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [ionic v2+](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) and not [ionic v1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/). Ionic 2 uses [Angular 2+](https://angular.io/docs) (not angularjs) and the language used is typescript.
The source files belong in `src/` and root module is **app.module.ts** and starting component is **app.component.ts**

If you want to still use ionic v1, it is supported (the file structure you are looking for is of ionic 1). You need to set `--type` as `ionic1` when you start the project.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/

```
ionic start myApp blank --type=ionic1
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using ionic v.1 Ionic version have the pattern in which the js folder holds app.js,controller.js etc.
Ionic v-2 uses modules instead of controllers.Ionic 2 is oriented for Object Oriented Concepts, thats why it is the form of class. If you want a peculiar type of version use the command : ionic start newapp blank --v1 .
But i would suggest you to use typescript which better than js.

Comment: will take a look into it...
currently having problem in building my app... it says 1 error `Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.0'` can u help